# Adding '&times;' to <span> tag via jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm designing a close button like this:

```html
<button type="button">
  <span>&times;</span>
</button>
```

Now, I wanna create that button by using jquery:

```js
$('#btn').click(function (){
  var span = $('<span>').text('&times;');
  var btn = $('<button>').prop('type', 'button').append(span);
  
  $('body').append(btn)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click me</button>
```

The compiler didn't convert `&times;` to `x`.

So, my question is: how to fix it?

Comment: Let's analyse the second line in your JS, `var span = $('<span>').text('&times;');`. So you declare a variable span (`var span =`) as the nodes with a CSS-selector `<span>`. Now there is your mistake. What do you think it will return? (maybe a `span` instead of a `button`) And is that a valid CSS-selector? (no)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. The html entities will be considered as a plain text when you use `.text()` to set that.

```js
$('#btn').click(function (){
  var span = $('<span>').html('&times;');
  var _btn = $('<button>').prop('type', 'button').append(span);
  
  $('body').append(_btn)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: @HappyCoding Happy coding!! :)